# How to use spring initializr on an existing empty repo in intelliJ idea CE?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Hey I'm very new to Java and spring. I am able to use spring initializr in my intelliJ idea CE when creating a new project, but I want to do the same for a blank repository that I cloned from a remote repository. I'm not even sure how to set the package name and groupId for this project through IntelliJ. Can someone help?

Comment: Am I right that you cloned empty repo from GitHub to your local computer and now want to initialize the spring application inside? In this case, just transfer all the files to this empty folder.